# Hibernate : org.hibernate.QueryParameterException: could not locate named parameter

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

I am working on a Spring-MVC application in which I would like to run a search on multiple variables at the same time. But the code keeps failing at setting parameter for the first value itself. I have no idea why. Any help would be nice.

ListStudents :

```
@Override
public List<Student> addHostSearchHistory(HostSearchHistory hostSearchHistory, Long hostId) {
    session = this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
    Host host = (Host) session.get(Host.class,hostId);
    host.getHostSearchHistorySet().add(hostSearchHistory);
    hostSearchHistory.setHsHistory(host);
    session.save(hostSearchHistory);
    session.flush();

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.append("from Student as s where ");

    if(!(hostSearchHistory.getCountry()==null)){
        sb.append("s.studentCountry=:").append(hostSearchHistory.getCountry());
    }
    if(!(hostSearchHistory.getCity()==null)){
        sb.append(" OR s.city=:").append(hostSearchHistory.getCity());
    }
    if(!(hostSearchHistory.getDrivingLicense()==null)){
        sb.append(" OR s.studentInfoDetails.drivingLicense=").append(hostSearchHistory.getDrivingLicense());
    }
    if(!(hostSearchHistory.getGender()==null)){
        sb.append(" OR s.gender=").append(hostSearchHistory.getGender());
    }
    if(!(hostSearchHistory.getMotherTongue()==null)){
        sb.append(" OR s.studentInfoDetails.motherTongue=:").append(hostSearchHistory.getMotherTongue());
    }
    if(!(hostSearchHistory.getSmoker()==null)){
        sb.append(" OR s.studentInfoDetails.smoker=").append(hostSearchHistory.getSmoker());
    }
    if(!(hostSearchHistory.getPreviousAuPair()==null)){
        sb.append(" OR s.studentInfoDetails.previouslyAuPair=").append(hostSearchHistory.getPreviousAuPair());
    }
    if(!(hostSearchHistory.getWillingToWork()==null)){
        sb.append(" OR s.studentInfoDetails.willingToWork=").append(hostSearchHistory.getWillingToWork());
    }
    if(!(hostSearchHistory.getWorkForSingleParent()==null)){
        sb.append(" OR s.studentInfoDetails.workForSingleParent=").append(hostSearchHistory.getWorkForSingleParent());
    }
    if(!(hostSearchHistory.getWorkingForDisabledChild()==null)){
        sb.append(" OR s.studentInfoDetails.workingForDisabledChild=").append(hostSearchHistory.getWorkingForDisabledChild());
    }
    if(!(hostSearchHistory.getOtherLanguages()==null)){
        sb.append(" OR s.studentInfoDetails.otherLanguages=:").append(hostSearchHistory.getOtherLanguages());
    }

    sb.append(" order by s.registrationDate desc");

    System.out.println("Sb.toString is "+sb.toString());

    Query query = session.createQuery(sb.toString());

// The code fails here
    if(!(hostSearchHistory.getCountry()==null)){
        query.setParameter("studentCountry",hostSearchHistory.getCountry());
    }
    if(!(hostSearchHistory.getCity()==null)){
        query.setParameter("city",hostSearchHistory.getCity());
    }
    if(!(hostSearchHistory.getDrivingLicense()==null)){
        query.setParameter("drivingLicense",hostSearchHistory.getDrivingLicense());
    }
    if(!(hostSearchHistory.getGender()==null)){
        query.setParameter("gender",hostSearchHistory.getGender());
    }
    if(!(hostSearchHistory.getMotherTongue()==null)){
        query.setParameter("motherTongue",hostSearchHistory.getMotherTongue());
    }
    if(!(hostSearchHistory.getSmoker()==null)){
        query.setParameter("smoker",hostSearchHistory.getSmoker());
    }
    if(!(hostSearchHistory.getPreviousAuPair()==null)){
        query.setParameter("previouslyAuPair",hostSearchHistory.getPreviousAuPair());
    }
    if(!(hostSearchHistory.getWillingToWork()==null)){
        query.setParameter("willingToWork",hostSearchHistory.getWillingToWork());
    }
    if(!(hostSearchHistory.getWorkForSingleParent()==null)){
        query.setParameter("workForSingleParent",hostSearchHistory.getWorkForSingleParent());
    }
    if(!(hostSearchHistory.getWorkingForDisabledChild()==null)){
        query.setParameter("workingForDisabledChild",hostSearchHistory.getWorkingForDisabledChild());
    }
    if(!(hostSearchHistory.getOtherLanguages()==null)){
        query.setParameter("otherLanguages",hostSearchHistory.getOtherLanguages());
    }

    List<Student> studentList = query.list();
    for(Student student : studentList){
        System.out.println("Student name is "+student.getUsername());
    }
   return studentList;

}
```

Output of sb.toString() :

```
Sb.toString is from Student as s where s.studentCountry=:Germany OR s.city=:Hamburg OR s.studentInfoDetails.drivingLicense=true OR s.gender=male OR s.studentInfoDetails.smoker=true OR s.studentInfoDetails.willingToWork=true OR s.studentInfoDetails.workingForDisabledChild=true order by s.registrationDate desc
```

Error log :

```
org.hibernate.QueryParameterException: could not locate named parameter [studentCountry]
    org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.ParameterMetadata.getNamedParameterDescriptor(ParameterMetadata.java:148)
    org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.ParameterMetadata.getNamedParameterExpectedType(ParameterMetadata.java:165)
    org.hibernate.internal.AbstractQueryImpl.determineType(AbstractQueryImpl.java:523)
    org.hibernate.internal.AbstractQueryImpl.setParameter(AbstractQueryImpl.java:493)
    com.journaldev.spring.dao.HostSearchHistoryDAOImpl.addHostSearchHistory(HostSearchHistoryDAOImpl.java:82)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
```

What am I doing wrong guys. Any help would be nice. Thanks a lot. :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer - you wrote this

```
query.setParameter("studentCountry",hostSearchHistory.getCountry());
```

but in your `sb.toString()` output you don't have `:studentCountry`.

Your whole first part of the method should have hardcoded parameter names, like `sb.append("s.studentCountry=:studentCountry")`, then the second part should work.

Or, use `sb.append("s.studentCountry='").append(hostSearchHistory.getCountry()).append("'");` and don't use parameters at all.

Comment: I like the 2nd option where I dont use parameters at all. I will try your solution, kindly wait. Do you mean I dont need to use query.setParameter if i use your last method.

Comment: Damn thing worked my friend, just one thing before I mark your answer, can you please tell me how I can make the search so it is case-insensitive, and search for similar stuff. Like When user types country as GerMAN, then Germany is a valid country in database and result should be returned.

Comment: Try something like this `sb.append("upper(s.studentCountry)='").append(hostSearchHistory.getCountry().toUpperCase()).append("'")`.

Comment: That is partially correct, what I mean is something like GER is also Germany.

Comment: Ok, didn't understand what you need, use this `sb.append("upper(s.studentCountry) like '").append("%" + hostSearchHistory.getCountry().to‌​UpperCase() + "%").append("'")`

Comment: Perfecto. That will be all my friend.

Answer (score 1):

You should use the first option suggested by Predrag. Using the second option has two major drawbacks:

1) Low performance. Database will not cache one prepared statement with bind variables, but many of them for all of the combinations of input parameters. That means parsing the statements all over again and purging other prepared statements out of the cache.

2) Security. Statements without bind variables are very vulnerable to SQL injection attacks. It may or may not be the case in you specific example, but generally, suppose that a malicious user (a hacker :)) inputs the following or similar filter criteria for the city or some other field:

```
' union select null, USERNAME || ',' || PASSWORD, null, null... from USER_PASSWORDS --
```

He would get all the username/passwords returned as student cities. :)
Of course this is just a general example, it may be some other query part or other sensitive data in your database in tables that actually exist.

Comment: Ok. I will make the necessary changes. And this seems more flexible too. Thanks for the input.